# I cannot access my server outside the network even after forwarding port 80

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-8.1, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I am using ubuntu server to host a server on a virtual machine(virtual box). I can access my server on my home network but when i try to access it using my external/public IP it send me back to the authentification page of my router.
So how can i make the server public?
Asked my ISP and they are saying that they don't block the ports

Comment: It seems you're trying from inside your own network? Try from a computer that is really outside of your own network. (Like a mobile phone.)

Comment: @Arjan great it is working from the mobile. So i can not access the server on the same network through my ip

Comment: Next time please edit your question with additional details. (Now the first answerer clearly has not seen your comment.)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to lack of NAT-loopback feature on your router (or such feature is disabled):

https://help.screenconnect.com/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN

Answer (score 0):

Your router is doing something you don't want it to.  It is not forwarding port 80 to the internal web server that you desire to respond to port 80.  If your router does have a "port forwarding" setting that says it will send port 80 to an internal IP address, then that setting is not causing the router to actually do that with the traffic.

It may be that the router is paying more attention to another setting.  Look for a setting related to "remote administration" (or something similar).  Make sure that the router does not permit such a thing to happen from the Internet.  (This is a good idea to do anyway, even if you don't want an internal web server on port 80, because the security provided by router firmwares have a reputation for being insufficient.  So if you see an option to move that functionality to another TCP port like 8000 or 8080, then don't do it.  Just make sure the feature is entirely disabled from external access.  If you ever do really want to adjust the router from remotely, then use a VPN or another technique to remotely control something from inside the network.)

I do agree that it sounds like this is not an ISP issue.  (If it was, then you wouldn't be seeing your router login.)

If you need further help, please supply details about your router (manufacturer, and model number...  also, if you placed a custom firmware/OS on it, let us know that.)  Reporting the firmware version might also be helpful.  Such details will be needed for us to effectively provide you with more specific steps.